# Lucene 4.6 include special characters as part of word during search

Tags: java, lucene

I have inherited a project which uses Lucene 4.6.0 to search xml documents.

Basically my problem seems to be this:

Searching a document with a text field containing `"otherwise authorized as such"` returns highlighted document when searching for any of those words, but if the
text field contains something like `"[otherwise authorized as such]"` then only a search for "authorized" returns a result.

I am guessing that lucene is not seeing `"[otherwise"` and `"such]"` as words because of the square brackets? 
Not being a lucene expert, even with documentation, I am stuck on this. Is there a way to customize an Analyzer to include "[" as part of word searches?

Thanks

Comment: so, you want to be able to search for terms like `[otherwise` ?

Comment: No I would like to search for "otherwise" and have lucene return results "[otherwise" and "otherwise". Currently, I am stripping the square brackets from the documents before writing them to the index, but this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually strip *bad* characters, you should write custom `Analyzer`, which will use [PatternReplaceCharFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilter.html), which could remove not needed symbols.

The example of this analyzer would be something like this:

```
class CustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

        @Override
        protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
            CharFilter cf = new PatternReplaceCharFilter(Pattern.compile("\\["), "", reader);
            cf = new PatternReplaceCharFilter(Pattern.compile("\\]"), "", cf);
            cf = new PatternReplaceCharFilter(Pattern.compile("\\)"), "", cf);
            cf = new PatternReplaceCharFilter(Pattern.compile("\\("), "", cf);
            return cf;
        }

        @Override
        protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
            final StandardTokenizer analyzer = new StandardTokenizer();
            TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(analyzer);
            tok = new LowerCaseFilter(tok);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(analyzer, tok);
        }
    }
```

Here I selected to replace only '' symbols.

After this indexing time filtering, you would be able to search as normal.

Full example of the code is located [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/java/SpecialCharactersSearch.java)

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I will try this out and update the post in a few days.